# Why hibernate add to my query cross join at the end

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, join

I am constructing and running a query via this Hibernate-based code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<hisaVO> hisa = criteria.from(hisaVO.class);
Root<EstablecVO> establec = criteria.from(EstablecVO.class);
Root<DisaVO> disa = criteria.from(DisaVO.class);
Root<RedVO> red1 = criteria.from(RedVO.class);
Root<MicroredVO> microred = criteria.from(MicroredVO.class);
Root<Unidad_EjecutoraVO> ue1 = criteria.from(Unidad_EjecutoraVO.class);
Join<hisaVO,EstablecVO> j1 = hisa.join("estab");
Join<EstablecVO,DisaVO> j2 = j1.join("disa") ;
Join<EstablecVO,RedVO> j3 = j1.join("red") ;
Join<EstablecVO,MicroredVO> j4 = j1.join("microred") ;
Join<EstablecVO,Unidad_EjecutoraVO> j5 = j1.join("ue") ;

criteria.multiselect(j3.get("red_nombre"), cb.count(hisa))
  .groupBy(red1.get("red_nombre"));

return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

The log shows Hibernate is implementing that via this corresponding SQL:

```
select
  redvo3_.red_nombre as col_0_0_,
  count(hisavo0_.id) as col_1_0_
from
  hisa hisavo0_
  inner join establec establecvo6_ 
    on hisavo0_.cod_estab=establecvo6_.COD_ESTAB
  inner join disa disavo7_
    on establecvo6_.cod_disa=disavo7_.id
  inner join red redvo8_
    on establecvo6_.cod_red=redvo8_.id
  inner join microred microredvo9_
    on establecvo6_.cod_mic=microredvo9_.id
  inner join unidad_ejecutora unidad_eje10_
    on establecvo6_.cod_ue=unidad_eje10_.id
  cross join establec establecvo1_
  cross join disa disavo2_
  cross join red redvo3_
  cross join microred microredvo4_
  cross join unidad_ejecutora unidad_eje5_
group by redvo3_.red_nombre
```

It seems to be adding extra, unexpected `cross join`s at the end of the query.  Why is it doing that?

Comment: the problem is because it adds at the end cross join and my query performance delay ... I have 10 million data :(

Comment: Are you asking about the last two cross joins -- the ones to `microredvo4_` and `unidad_eje5_`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger What I ask is because it adds all cross join  if it is already inner join ...This delay causes the query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You give your query multiple roots via multiple invocations of `CriteriaQuery.from()`.  Each one after the first is reflected in the final query via a `cross join`.  That's roughly what it *means* to be a query root.

You do not need to (and should not) use `CriteriaQuery.from()` to add entities to the query that you mean to be associated via inner joins corresponding to mapped relationships -- those you connect via a `Join` used as the `Selection` when you run your query.

Comment: "You do not need to (and should not) use CriteriaQuery.from() to add entities to the query that you mean to be associated via inner joins"

You're assuming that the tables will be joined on a primary key. If they have to be joined on an arbitrary key, there is no choice but to add the other table's root. It's a shame that the criteria API has this limitation.

Comment: Point taken, @Amalgovinus.  I have rephrased to specify inner joins *corresponding to mapped relationships*, which I think is what it comes down to logically.  In practice, those will indeed be joins on primary key, but I think even joins on primary key require a query root + filter criterion where they don't correspond to a mapped relationship.

Comment: Example code would be nice here